# Best way to do PHP development on OS X

Tags: php, macos, debugging

I just got a Mac with OS X (10.6.8). What options do I have to do serious PHP developement, including a debugger?

I don't ask about what IDE to use. I'm not sure what is the best way to get PHP including XDebug (or any other professional debugger) working. I heard that the Mac comes with Apache and PHP preinstalled. Where can I find any documentation about this. Should I just add MySql and work with this? Or should I go for MAMP or XAMPP. What would be the benefit of this installs over the built in?

I found a lot of descriptions about how to compile XDebug from scratch. Non of them worked for me. Isn't there an easier way of getting a debugger working for OS X?

I'm also ready to upgrade the Mac to the latest OS X, if this is of any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot more googling and try and error I found a very nice and easy to install solution which works great for me:

1. Installed [MacGDBp](http://www.bluestatic.org/software/macgdbp/).
2. Installed [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/de/index.html).
3. Opened the `php.ini` at `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini` and uncommented the only line containing the `xdebug.so` file.
4. Added this lines at the end of php.ini

   ```
   xdebug.remote_enable=1
   xdebug.remote_host=localhost 
   xdebug.remote_port=9000
   xdebug.remote_autostart=1
   ```
5. After restarting apache MacGDBp stoped at the first PHP line.
6. Done!

Answer (score 13):

In the age of virtualization

- vagrant box full of ubuntu and zend CE server
- zend studio for ide and zend debugger works out of the box
- you can config it to use x-debug just apt-get it

this way you'll keep your os-x clean and have all the necessary stuff inside a portable/deployable virtual machine that runs on background or can be launched from any machine you might be using today or tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

I use my MacBook Pro for PHP development every day, including XDebug.  I've set it up both on Snow Leopard and on Lion.  It's been a while, but does this link help you? 
http://maestric.com/doc/mac/apache_php_mysql_snow_leopard

For XDebug, what problems are you experiencing?  I also wrote this guide on my blog for two simple ways of installing PHP extensions on a Mac: http://software.curtisfarnham.com/2011/10/30/how-to-install-php-extensions-in-mac-os-x-lion/